# Error in VHDL (Xilinx): failed to link the design

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

why I get error in VHDL for this? Also, sometimes: cannot do process as a process failed previously?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the process failing part, it seems that Xilinx tool writers may have an issue try restarting them and if needed, your machine as well.

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried restart but no luck. It keeps saying the same. I try to put simple andgate and I get both errors.

Comment: Try process rerun all

Comment: [Xilinx - Documentation: Running and Stopping Processes](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/ise_p_running_processes.htm)

Comment: Thank you I not get process fail now. (I did process: rerun all)

Answer (score 42):

Permanent solution 1: on win 10
Find the "`installation directory\Xilinx\14.x\ISE_DS\ISE\gnu\MinGW\5.0.0\nt\libexec\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\collect2.exe`" and delete it and re-run the emulator, the problem resolved! !

Just delete this or cut and paste somewhere as else, now re-run the code or test bench it will work.

Please accept the solution if find working

No need to update any minGW

Answer (score 4):

I found answer! [Look at ningunos answer](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Simulation-and-Verification/ERROR-Simulator-861-Failed-to-link-the-design/td-p/261956/page/2) and put "fuse" file in: `C:\Xilinx\14.x\ISE_DS\ISE\bin\nt`

Answer (score 2):

1. Download latest version of MinGW
2. Copy all the content from the `MinGW` folder into `Xilinx\14.2\ISE_DS\ISE\gnu\MinGW\5.0.0\nt`

Now it should be working.

Answer (score 2):

just run the 64bit variant of ISE

Comment: For me the 64-bit variant crashes.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/62380.html) worked for me.
Solved windows 10 issue with xilinx.
I tried this solution (as mentioned in link): 
"ISE 14.7 64-bit - Turning off SmartHeap:"

1) Navigate to the following ISE install directory: \Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\lib\nt64\

2) Rename the file "libPortability.dll" to "libPortability.dll.orig".

3) Copy the "libPortabilityNOSH.dll" file to the same folder, and rename it to "libPortability.dll".

4) Repeat steps 1-3 in the following folder: \Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\common\lib\nt64\

The above steps substitute the original "libPortability.dll" with a "libPortability.dll" file that has SmartHeap disabled, the NOSmartHeap (NOSH) version.

This does not negatively impact the operation of the tools, and should successfully work around the ISE 14.7 crash documented above.

Comment: Please include all the information needed to solve the question. Enriching your answer with a summary of the steps taken, along with the external link, would be ideal as articles on external sites may be removed in time.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you soooo much, i tried all the other solutions with MinGW and such and none of them work, but this one worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse the answer belowed is from **

> Mr. Purohit Gaurav on dt of 11 jul 2016

**

i tried the same one on **windows 8** it works perfect...........

i just cut the collect2.exe and paste it somewhere else

```
Permanent solution 1: on win 8 Find the "installation directory \ Xilinx \ 14.x \ ISE_DS \ ISE \ gnu \ MinGW \ 5.0.0 \ nt \ libexec \ gcc \ mingw32 \ 3.4.2 \ collect2.exe" and delete it and re-run the emulator, the problem resolved! !

Just delete this or cut and paste somewhere as else, now re-run the code or test bench it will work.
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem with the compiler, but when I installed the compiler, I faced the error "failed to link the design"

The solution that worked for me is to **cleanup the project files**

On the taskbar click on **Project** **>** **Cleanup Project Files**