# I get the following error in VHDL: Failed to link the design process "Simulate Behaviour model failed"

Tags: vhdl

A Similar question was asked but there has been no real answer. Could someone please inform me of a possible way to fix this error?

Comment: Are you using Xilinx? If so, are you trying to run a simulation or are you just trying to synthesize it?

Comment: I am using Xilinx and trying to simulate it. Do you know what I should do?

Comment: To simulate you have to first synthesize the module and then once you know it works you create a test bench for it and double click "Simulate Behavioral Model."

Comment: I've done that. It seems to be working fine when synthesising but when I try and simulate it using a test bench, it gives me the error...

Comment: Look at my post, I found answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033297/error-in-vhdl-xilinx-failed-to-link-the-design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this, download fuse and place in `C:\Xilinx\14.x\ISE_DS\ISE\bin\nt`